# PDFダウンロード時に複数回リクエストが発生し、初回と2回目のURLエンコードの結果が異なり404となる

Tags: java, tomcat, iis

ブラウザ（IE11）からファイル名に日本語を含むPDFファイル（10MB程度）をダウンロードし、これをブラウザ上で表示しています。
同一ファイルでも1回で通信が終了できる環境と、2回目のリクエストが発生する環境（別tomcat上で動作する同一アプリケーション）があります。
後者の事例をtomcatのログで調べた結果、初回のGETのURLエンコーディングはUTF-8ですが、2回目のGETではShift_JISになっており、ここで404エラーが発生しています。
この現象を調べていたところ、全く同じ現象について質問しているページを発見しましたが、回答が付いていませんでした。

[URLエンコードについて - Adobe Support Community - 8724433](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-acrobat-dc-for-mobile%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0/url%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/td-p/8724433?profile.language=ja)

日本語を含まない大きいPDFファイルをリクエストした場合、初回GETは200ですが、後続の複数回のGETで206を大量に返していました。
ファイルを分割して返すかどうかとURLエンコードが変わるのは別問題ですが、無関係ではないと考えております。
調べる観点やTomcatの設定見直しなどアドバイスがあればお願いします。

開発言語：Java
APサーバ：Tomcat9
OS：Windows10

Comment: 少なくとも IE11 は既にサポート切れなので、がんばって不具合詳細の調査を行っても無駄な努力に終わりそうな気がするっス。 Edge でも再現するということなら、そう書いてもらうほうが読者の側の興味を引けそう。

Comment: HTTPプロトコルの話なのでクライアント(UA)は関係ありません。どういうリクエストにどういうレスポンスがあった話なのか正確に記述を行い、再現コードを提示してください。

Comment: IE11のAdobe PDF Readerアドオンが有効で、PDFはそのアドオンを用いてIE11上に表示されるということであってますでしょうか？また、Adobe PDF Readerアドオンを無効にすることで、正常にダウンロードできたりしますでしょうか？